# Opening file urls from the command line on OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome

When I run

```
open file:///Users/me/somefile.html#bar
```

It switches to Chrome (my default browser) but doesn't actually open the file. What gives? Is there any way to make this work?

I don't want any solutions that hard-code the use of Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this seems to be a bug in Chrome. I tried it with `open -a Firefox file:///...` and it works fine.

Edit: Restarted Chrome and now it works. Very odd.